# Unable to install Inkscape in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: software-installation, 17.10, inkscape

I had tried to install **Inkscape** in *Ubuntu 17.10*. It downloaded for some minute but then the connection got broken. When I tried to download it again, the following message appeared :-

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 1):

You tried to install the **snap for `inkscape`**. Maybe there is a temporary problem, maybe a more serious problem with this snap. (The message indicates that the snap is being upgraded.)

**But it works to install `inkscape` from the repositories** in the classical way. I tested in Ubuntu 17.10 running live.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install inkscape
```

and the result was a working `inkscape` program.

Comment: thanks very well  i installed it by an other way thanks for your help

Comment: @douaksofiane, I'm glad you found a way to to install `inkscape` :-)